# problemas con tipo de variables utilizando ion-input

Tags: ionic, angular-directivas

Realizando un proyecto con **ionic 3** he tenido un problema bastante extraños, estoy trabajando en mi archivo `ts` utilizo dos variable de tipo numero, pero en mi archivo `html` tengo dos elementos `<ion-input>` de `type="number"` y con la directiva `[(ngModel)]`, pero al modificar los valores de las variables por teclado mi archivo `ts` comienza a entender estas variable como tipo `string`, dejo el código a continuación, el asunto es que comparo si un numero es mayor que otro pero me da resultados inesperados

**page.ts**

```
variable1: number;
variable2: number; 

constructor() {
    var variableMayor
    if(this.variable1 > this.variable2){
        variableMayor = this.variable1 
        console.log('variable mayor es variable1', variableMayor )

    }else{
        variableMayor = this.variable2 
        console.log('variable mayor es variable2', variableMayor )
    }
 }
```

**page.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <ion-row >

        <ion-col col-6 >
            <h6 >Variable</h6>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="variable1" type="number" ></ion-input>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-6 >
            <h6 >Variable</h6>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="variable2" type="number" ></ion-input>
        </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: He comprobado tú código tal cual y funciona bien: [ver demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nfe1v3)

Answer (score 0):

cambia las variables

```
variable1: number;
variable2: number;
```

a

```
variable1: any;
variable2: any;
```

como ya tienes `type="number"` en el ion-input  no tendrías que sobre validar que sea numero

no se si ya solucionaste el error